# How to not save a field to Fireabse if left empty

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page with TextFormFields - how do I NOT save a field to Firebase if the user leaves it empty? I'm guessing `if` statements with `.isEmpty`, but I'm not sure where to implement them:

```
onPressed: () async {
          final uid =
              await TheProvider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();

          //save data to firebase

          widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
          widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text);
          widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
          widget.contact.rating = int.parse(fourController.text);
          widget.contact.instagram = fiveController.text;
          widget.contact.birthday = int.parse(sixController.text);
          widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;

          await db
              .collection("userData")
              .doc(uid)
              .collection("Contacts")
              .add(widget.contact.toJson());
```

Models file

```
class Contact {
int rating;
String name;
String location;
int phoneNumber;
String instagram;
int birthday;
String notes;


Contact(this.name, this.phoneNumber, this.location, this.rating,
        this.instagram, this.birthday, this.notes);


Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'Name': name,
    'PhoneNumber': phoneNumber,
    'Location': location,
    'Rating': rating,
    'Instagram': instagram,
    'Birthday': birthday,
    'Notes': notes,
    
  };
}
```

An example of one of the TextFormFields

```
TextFormField(
                controller: fourController,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.tealAccent),
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                decoration:
                    textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Rating'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int.tryParse when intialising text editing controllers instead of int.parse (for integer TextFormFields).

Answer (score 1):

Usually if I have/might have empty fields for info a user doesn't set I just upload it as null, and when displaying/using the info I handle the null values. (Don't display birthday `if(birthday==null)`).

If you don't want to do that, how about you first create a map in the `Contact` class, and remove the empty values from the map before turning the map to `JSON`? I think this would be easiest.

Here is how to remove values from a map in dart:

```
Map map = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'};
map.remove(2); //enter the key you wish to remove
```

Combine that with if statements checking if every value is null, and removing it from the map if it is.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I'm getting an error code for the new Map - 

`Map contacts = {name: 'Name'` etc..

"The instance variable 'name' can't be accessed in an initialiser"

Comment: @ashf That's a whole different error, I don't know how to solve that when in a custom class but in a widget it means you can't do what you're trying to do until after the widget is built.

Comment: I get you. If doing your first suggested method, where would one put the `if` statement? TextEditingController? on the async call before adding to firebase as `JSON`?